# SQL Create Procedure Abort Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon all -

I have a temporary stored procedure that needs to be run as a hotfix in several places and I'd like to abort the creation and compilation of the SP if the version of the application is not exactly what I enter. I have the basic idea working but I'd like the messages to come out without all the schema issues from trying to compile the SP.

Here is basically what I have:

```
IF EXISTS ... DROP PROCEDURE 

SELECT TOP 1 Version INTO #CurrentVersion FROM Application_Version ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #CurrentVersion WHERE Version = 10)
RAISERROR ('This is for U10 only. Check the application version.', 20, 1) WITH LOG

CREATE PROCEDURE ....
```

The RAISERROR causes the SP to not end up in the DB and I do get an error but I also end up with schema errors due to schema changes in the past. Due to the SP needing to be the first statement in the batch I can't use IF / ELSE and NOEXEC yields the same results as RAISERROR (without the error).

Any ideas for what can be done to get all of the same results as above without the SP checking the schema if it hits the RAISERROR so I don't end up with a bunch of extra messages reported?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the error condition to stop execution of the script, which is possible in [SQLCMD mode of the query editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) with a simple `:on error exit`:

```
:on error exit

SELECT TOP 1 Version INTO #CurrentVersion FROM Application_Version ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #CurrentVersion WHERE Version = 10)
   RAISERROR ('This is for U10 only. Check the application version.', 16, 1);
go

IF EXISTS ... DROP PROCEDURE 
go

CREATE PROCEDURE ....
...
go
```

With this in place there is no need to raise severity 20. Severity 16 is enough, which will take care of the ERRORLOG issue you complain.

Answer (score 0):

The `RETURN` statement will exit out of a SP. When doing error checking, put a `BEGIN` and `END` after your `IF` statement and after your `RAISERROR` put a `RETURN` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here. My approach would be as follows, because I feel that it provides the best flow:

```
IF EXISTS ... DROP PROCEDURE 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Application_Version WHERE Version = 10)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'CREATE PROCEDURE blablabla AS
        BEGIN
            -- Your Procedure HERE
        END'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END ELSE
    RAISERROR ('This is for U10 only. Check the application version.', 20, 1) WITH LOG
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually fits best with what I'm looking to do. The SQLCMD would work perfectly except I'm looking to protect against people who clearly didn't pay enough attention to the documentation and naming of SP and people who missed a version note likely wouldn't see another note to switch into SQLCMD mode. Thanks for the help everyone!